# dockerized postgres - lock file "postmaster.pid" is empty

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm experiencing issues using the official Postgres docker image, something that never happened on this machine. 
I'm using that through docker-compose but when running `docker-compose up`, the db container does not start, here's the error:

```
db_1         | 2019-04-19 22:20:27.180 UTC [1] FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" is empty
db_1         | 2019-04-19 22:20:27.180 UTC [1] HINT:  Either another server is starting, or the lock file is the remnant of a previous server startup crash.
```

I tried several times to remove the image so it then will be re-pulled, but hasn't solved the problem.

I'm using Docker for Mac 2.0.0.3 (31259)

here's the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    entrypoint: sh -c "python3 /var/www/my_project/manage.py migrate --noinput &&
                python3 /var/www/my_project/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "9001:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/my_project
    depends_on:
    - db
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    environment:
      - DB_SERVER=db
      - DB_NAME=postgres
      - DB_USER=postgres
  db:
    ports:
        - "9432:5432"
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/postgresql
volumes:
  database:
```

Any help on this?

Comment: would you pls paste your `docker-compose.yml` here as well?

Comment: @Enix added to the main message, thank you.

Comment: can u start your db container without specifying the volumes? I suspect the error is related to your database volume...

Comment: @Enix commented out both volumes section, but I got the same error.

Comment: @Enix I'm tempted to reset to factory default or even reinstall docker at this point, I don't know what else to do. Now I have the same error with other projects using db...

Comment: how about creating another container directly with `docker run -it -d --name db postgres`? or even older version: `docker run -it -d --name db postgres:9`

Comment: @Enix `docker run -it -d --name db postgres` -> it runs! I cal also access to the container through `docker exec -it db bash`.
What I can do now?

Comment: @Enix resetting docker for mac solved the problem for now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove the pid file manually from the volume mounted by the container. Something like this:

Search the volume:

```
docker inspect container-name
```

Search for the directory where the volume is stored:

```
...
"Mounts": [
  {
    "Type": "volume",
    "Name": "9009b4e54686dc36f797a15fd8fc09213f3e8949583b823525881c010f2fe347",
    "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/9009b4e54686dc36f797a15fd8fc09213f3e8949583b823525881c010f2fe347/_data",
```

Now delete the pid file:

```
rm /var/lib/docker/volumes/9009b4e54686dc36f797a15fd8fc09213f3e8949583b823525881c010f2fe347/_data/
```

After this you might get this error message:

```
lock file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock" is empty
```

This can be fixed by overwriting that file with a file containing a number:

```
echo 12345 > bla
docker cp bla container-name:/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock
docker restart container-name
```

Answer (score 0):

It could happen because you are starting the PostgreSQL server when you are still running your PostgreSQL server.
Try

```bash
pg_ctl stop
```

then

```bash
pg_ctl start
```

or

```bash
pg_ctl restart
```